# In Integration Which term of $ uv $ would be $u$ & $ v$

Tags: integration

Like at
$$ \int \sin at \ e^{- st}\, dt$$ which term we will Consider as $u$ and which Term we will cosider as $v'$ ...

Is there any rule to choose it ??
For example, see [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031675/sign-problem-laplace-transform-of-sinat?rq=1%20/).

He takes the sine term as $u$ & exponential term as $v'$?
Can't it be Reverse ???
Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. In it's current state it is neither self-contained nor understandable.

Comment: I guess you mean while integrating by parts. Try both, and write an answer of your result.

Answer (score 0):

A preliminary method has been deviced, which is applicable to many of the by parts integration is: ILATE 
I - Inverse trigonometric
L- logarithmic 
A - algebraic
T - trigonometric
E - exponential functions respectively 
So the one which comes first is to be taken  as u ( the one whose differentiation is to be done) and v is the second function . So this helps a little in chosing the function. In your case sin to be the first function and exponential to be the second.